# Move to https://www, when it is www or http:// or without www and http://?

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2, httpd.conf

I am using Zend framework where i have nice looking url controllers. Following .htaccess is working but its making SEO to see us as four links for one page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

I need to do following fix using htaccess:

> www.stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url =
>   https://www.stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url
>
> stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url =
>   https://www.stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url
>
> http://www.stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url =
>   https://www.stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url
>
> http://stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url =
>   https://www.stackoverflow.com/nice-looking-url

How to do it correctly using htaccess? so that above input urls are safely landing with https://www. in front always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your full .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule - main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

## turn on https in same rule - sub domain
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure to use a new browser to test your changes to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: 1 problem. i have few subdomains. after applying your version all works except all the subdomain's are becoming like this: `https://www.sms.domain.com/otherclients` instead of remaining as `https://sms.domain.com/otherclients`

Comment: So you don't want www before sub domains but want www before main domain?

Comment: Exactly. `https://www.example.com` but `https://subdomain1.example.com` should remain with subdomain because of some random DNS routing is used.

Comment: When i try `http://example.com` it goes to `https://example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com`